# How do I create view on table with jsonb array entries in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, view, jsonb

I know there are a bunch of similar questions but I still couldn't find one for my explicit problem.

I have a postgres table that looks like this:

```
|---------------------|----------------------------------------|-------------------------|
|           id        |                    data                |       timestamp         |  
|---------------------|----------------------------------------|-------------------------|
|          1          |  [{"key1": "value1", "key2":value2"}   |   2020-06-09 13:15:00   |               
|                     |   ,{"key1": "value1", "key2":value2"}] |                         |
|---------------------|----------------------------------------|-------------------------|
|          2          |  [{"key1": "value1", "key2":value2"}   |   2020-06-09 13:20:00   |               
|                     |   ,{"key1": "value1", "key2":value2"}] |
```

I want to create a view on this table so that each key value in the jsonb data column gets it's own column.

I played around with the json_array_elements and json_b each function but I could not get it to work after all.

In the best case this View would be generated generically with any amount of keyNames.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Edit:

I have following example Structure for my jsonb array:

```
[{
  "key1": "value",
  "id": "fac30fe9-a39c-445a-84de-637a199f1dfa",
  "subobject1": {
    "subkey1": "subvalue1",
    "subkey2": "subvalue2"
  },
  "key3": "value3"
},
  key1": "value",
  "id": "fac30fe9-a39c-445a-84de-637a199f1dfa",
  "subobject1": {
  "subkey1": "subvalue1",
  "subkey2": "subvalue2"
},
  "key3": "value3"
  }  
]
```

Comment: "*In the best case this View would be generated generically with any amount of keyNames.*" that's not possible. The names, number and data types of the columns of a SELECT statement have to be know **before** the query is actually executed. You can't write a query that determines its output columns while it's running. You will have to hard-code the key names in your view

Comment: I could work around that limitation.
So far i got following query:
```
CREATE VIEW viexX AS
WITH 
A AS (
SELECT
    Id
   ,jsonb_array_elements(data) AS messStellen
FROM "3"
)
SELECT *
FROM A

```
Which creates individual entries for each element in the json b array field but i am still missing individual collumns

Comment: I don't understand how you intend to turn array elements into columns. What if each array has a different number of array elements and keys?

Comment: The array structure is identical for any given row and the table is known beforehand. The only things that can change is the number of json objects in the array and the structure of the json array from one table to another.

Comment: I edited my jsonb array structure to the question, maybe that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured out a solution that i can currently live with:

```
    CREATE VIEW viewX as
        SELECT id, 
               messStellen ->> 'uuid' as uuid
        FROM (
            WITH 
            A AS (
            SELECT
                Id
               ,jsonb_array_elements(data) AS messStellen
            FROM "3"
            )
            SELECT *
            FROM A
            ) x
```

However, I would be grateful if anyone could point me into the right direction how i could template such a query to be applicable to a table where the data field could consist of json objects with other keys.